# MySQL query using CASE to SELECT multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have the following query which works correctly:

```
SELECT Future.enemy_type,
CASE WHEN Future.enemy_type = 'square' THEN Users.color
ELSE ''
END AS color,
CASE WHEN Future.enemy_type = 'square' THEN Users.user_ID
ELSE ''
END AS ID,
CASE WHEN Future.enemy_type = 'headquarters' THEN Users.username
ELSE ''
END AS username,
CASE WHEN Future.enemy_type = 'headquarters' THEN Users.home_lat
ELSE ''
END AS lat
FROM Future
LEFT JOIN Users ON Future.user_ID_affected = Users.user_ID
WHERE Future.time > 1539503510
AND Future.time <= 1539503512
AND Future.user_ID = 10;
```

However, is there a more efficient way to write it? I need to SELECT a few values based on the conditional (e.g. square or headquarters), but I understand that CASE can only return 1 value. However, it seems inefficient to check the condition with a new CASE statement each time I want to return one value.

Some people on SO have suggested using JOIN statements for similar queries, but I'm not sure how this would work with multiple conditionals?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is likely a problem with database design and lack of proper normalisation (though I won't say it categorically as you haven't provided schemata and semantics). Even so, what is bad about returning all the found info? Your client code can very easily ignore the unneeded data (unless your SQL server is somewhere in Siberia and you're watching every byte of the transport).

Comment: The volume of data returned wasn't my issue with the query above, however since you mentioned it, it is an issue as this is an MMO. Every byte counts, and no extraneous data should be returned to clients to prevent potential hacking/security issues. I like to follow this principle anyway, regardless of the application.

Comment: In an MMO it would be extremely weird to allow game clients to issue SQL requests to your server directly, though. When I say "client code" here, I am talking about the SQL client, which should be your MMO server, not the game client.

Comment: Yes, that would be extremely weird :) This query is within an PHP file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like the [`IF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function for simple statements:

```
SELECT
    Future.enemy_type,
    IF (Future.enemy_type = 'square', Users.color, '') AS color,
    IF (Future.enemy_type = 'square', Users.user_ID, '') AS ID,
    IF (Future.enemy_type = 'headquarters', Users.username, '') AS username,
    IF (Future.enemy_type = 'headquarters', Users.home_lat, '') AS lat
FROM Future
LEFT JOIN Users
    ON Future.user_ID_affected = Users.user_ID
WHERE
    Future.time > 1539503510  AND
    Future.time <= 1539503512 AND
    Future.user_ID = 10;
```

Comment: Thanks - that query returns the same values as my original one, but is much less verbose. I guess you've also answered my implicit question: there is no "elegant" way to omit multiple conditionals such as my one (IF (Future.enemy_type = xxx). Thank you.